# Angular firebase user error while using google authentication

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication, observable, google-authentication

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  user$:Observable<firebase.User> ;
  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 
    this.user$ = afAuth.authState;
  }
  login(){
    this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
  logout(){
    this.afAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

I am using angular 12 and firebase for google auth but getting error near  this.user$ = afAuth.authState; ;
Type 'Observable<User | null>' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
Type 'User | null' is not assignable to type 'User'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'User'

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the user that comes from Firebase can be null, and your code doesn't allow for that.

The simplest solution is to allow the `null` too by changing your observable to:

```
user$:Observable<firebase.User?>;
```

Comment: Still I face the same error at this.user$ = afAuth.authState;

Comment: The exact same error? That seems unlikely after making a change. I'd expect at least the "Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'User'" part to be gone.

Comment: Hey @SoumyoDeepto Any update here?